# Is there any way to get touch/click events in secondary displays connected to Android device?

Tags: java, android, display, presentation

I am developing an Android application which displays a particular screen in a secondary display when it is connected, but it is not taking any touch/click events on that display even though the display is receptive to touch.

I am using Android's **Presentation** class for this. When the secondary display is connected it gracefully displays the class that I have developed which extends to Presentation class. But none of the click or touch events are working in this class. I believe the Presentation class does not allow any touch or is there any other way other than Presentation class for me which **allows touch events in the secondary display**? Please help.

The class is as follows:

```
public class PresentationActivity extends Presentation {

    private TextView text;


    private PresentationActivity presentation;
    private Context context;
    private Display display;
    Button btn_click;


    PresentationActivity(Context outerContext, Display display) {
        super(outerContext, display);
        context = outerContext;
        this.display = display;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_presentation);

        TextView text = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        btn_click = findViewById(R.id.btn_click);

        this.text = text;

        btn_click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Click is working for display number " + display.getDisplayId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("CLICK_TRACK", display.getDisplayId()+"");
            }
        });

    }
}
```